# JavaScript calender date picker not storing future dates

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, datepicker

I am using date picker.Problem is this when user select date before the current date then it is stored in database but when user select date that is coming in future ,that date is not accepted instead it display this date 1970-01-01.

**Code**

```
 jQuery('.calendar').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
```

What should i do in this case that future date can also be selected.

**Code php**

```
   if(isset($pst_data['dob'])){
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pst_data['dob'])));
    $sqldata['dob'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pst_data['dob']));}
```

Comment: show us your php code plz.

Comment: create fiddle please

Comment: @Mit.agile i have edited the question

Comment: by default it allows to select the future dates...see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/8w8v9/

Comment: @Ruhul yes it is working fine but here it is not working

Comment: @Waqas_aamer  do one thing .. put static future date in your php code which you are sending from your datepicker dynamically and then check what's happening .. by doing this we are making sure whether we are getting any issue from datepicker javascript or from our php side.

Comment: @Mit.agile i have done this. I think strtotime is not accepting the future dates. what should i do in that case

Comment: @Waqas_aamer it should or will accept future date .. as strtotime will only convert the in the format you want. Can you give me the sample of code with static future date you are trying so that i can look further..

Comment: @Waqas_aamer so now atleast you are sure that we do not have any issue related to datepicker .. correct ?

Comment: Yes sir @Mit.agile issue is with strtotime

Comment: and it is still not converting the future date format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121316/discussion-between-mit-agile-and-waqas-aamer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note the different interpretation of - and / in the date. If you use a - php will determine it to be DD-MM, if you use a / php will determine it to be MM-DD.

```
$date = "07/12/2018"; // your future date in mm/dd/yyyy format
$your_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Change your date format from jquery's datepicker to this **`dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',`**

Or check this demo example in which i have set the date format as **mm/dd/yy** http://jsfiddle.net/tz53ujqo/15/